# Receive offline messages with Quickblox

Tags: chat, quickblox

Users do not receive offline messages when they get online.

Could you please explain why users do not receive offline messages?

Comment: could you provide more info about your app workflow

Comment: Hi lgor, I am using an example of Quickblox, simple-chat, and there are two accounts. First, account1 sends an offline message to account2. Then, account2 does not receive it when getting online.

Comment: What do you mean 'offline' message?
User1 send message to User2, but User2 is offline now?

Comment: Yes, User2 gets online, but he does not receive message.why?

Comment: @user2164530 did you found any solution for this? I am also facing same problem..

Answer (score 1):

I used below query to fetch the previous messages.

```
let resPage = QBResponsePage(limit:100, skip:self.messageHandler.messageArray.count)
let parameters = ["sort_desc" : "date_sent"]
QBRequest.messagesWithDialogID(createdDialog.ID, 
                               extendedRequest: parameters, 
                               forPage: resPage, 
                               successBlock: 
                               {(response: QBResponse, messages: [QBChatMessage]?, responcePage: QBResponsePage?) in
                               /*** You will get all the previous messages ***/
                               }, 
                               errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in
                               /*** Some error occured while getting messages ***/
                               })
```

Comment: Did you set "save_to_history" flag for saving the sent message to history.